# How do I get the folder structure through the smugmug api (phpsmug)

Tags: php, api

I am using smugphp and have completed all of the login stuff above this block of code.  I am trying to get the folder structure that I have created in the smugmug website.  Unfortunately this only gives me that category and the name of the leaf of the folder tree.  There doesn't seem to be any way to get the intermediate folders.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$categories=$f->categories_get();

$subcategories=$f->subcategories_getAll();

echo "CATEGORIES<br>";
for ($i=0;$i<count($categories);$i++){
  print_r($categories[$i]);
  echo "<br><br>";
}
echo "subcategories<br>";
for ($i=0;$i<count($subcategories);$i++){
  print_r($subcategories[$i]);
  echo "<br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best or cleanest solution, but with the code below I am able to trick smugmug into giving me what I want.  I force it to do a depth first search and then ignore duplicates.  I hope this helps other people, but please let me know if there is a better solution out there.

```
<?php

require_once("phpSmug/phpSmug.php");

class Smugmug{
    private $f;
    private $folders;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->f=new phpSmug("APIKey=MfDv7qWG8VZt2tSK2DV7rZx10YXnu7UF","APIVer=1.2.2");
$this->f->login("APIKey=MfDv7qWG8VZt2tSK2DV7rZx10YXnu7UF","EmailAddress=EMAIL@gmail.com","Password=PASSWORD");
        $this->folders=[];
    }

    public function get_folders(){
        $this->folders=$this->_get_folders();
    }

    private function new_id($id,$folders){
        if (!isset($folders)){
            return False;
        }
        for ($i=0;$i<count($folders);$i++){
            if ($id==$folders[$i]['id']){
                return False;
            }
            if ($this->new_id($id,$folders[$i]['subfolders'])==False){
                return False;
            }
        }
        return True;
    }
    private function _get_folders($id=-1){
        $folders=[];
        if ($id==-1){
            $categories = $this->f->categories_get();
        } else {
            $categories = $this->f->subcategories_get("CategoryID=$id");
        }
        $k=0;
        for ($i=0;$i<count($categories);$i++){
            $folder['id']=$categories[$i]['id'];
            if ($this->new_id($folder['id'],$folders)){
                $folder['name']=$categories[$i]['Name'];
                $folders[$i]=$folder;
                $subfolders=$this->_get_folders($folder['id']);
                $folders[$i]['subfolders']=$subfolders;
            }
        }
        return $folders;
    }
    public function print_folders(){
        $this->_print_folders($this->folders);
    }
    private function _print_folders($folders,$prefix=""){
        for ($i=0;$i<count($folders);$i++){
            echo $prefix.$folders[$i]['name']."<br>";
            $this->_print_folders($folders[$i]['subfolders'],$prefix."-");
        }
    }
}

?>
```